# Database Design for 2D Matrix Algebra

Tags: database, database-design, matrix

Can anyone advise on a database design/DBMS for storing 2D Time Series Matrix data. To allow for quick BACK END algebraic calculations: e.g:

Table A,B,C..
Col1: Date- Timestamp
col2: Data- Array? (Matrix Data)

- SQL Psuedo Code

INSERT INTO TABLE C
SELECT
Multiply A.Data A by B.Data
Where Matrix A Start Date = Matrix B Start Date
And Matrix A End Date = Matrix B End Date

Essentially set the co-ordinates for the calculation.

Comment: Can you be more elaborate ? Its not clear yet. What the table will contain and what will be fetched from It.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with matrix algebra is determining what is a domain on the matrix for data modelling purposes.  Is it a value?  Is it a matrix as a whole?  This is not a pre-defined question, so I will give you two solutions and what the tradeoffs are.

Solution 1:  Value in a matrix cell is a domain:

```
 CREATE TABLE matrix_info (
     x_size int,
     y_size int,
     id serial not null unique,
     timestamp not null,
 );

 CREATE TABLE matrix_cell (
     matrix_id int references matrix_info(id),
     x int,
     y int,
     value numeric not null,
     primary key (matrix_id, x, y)
);
```

The big concern is that this does not enforce matrix sizes very well.  Additionally a missing value could be used to represent 0, or might not be allowed.  The idea of using a matrix as a whole as a domain has some attractiveness.  In this case:

```
CREATE TABLE matrix (
  id serial not null unique,
  timestamp not null,
  matrix_data numeric[]
);
```

Note that many db's including PostgreSQL will enforce that an array is actually a matrix. Then you'd need to write your own functions for multiplication etc.  I would recommend doing this in an object-relational way and on PostgreSQL since it is quite programmable for this sort of thing.  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE matrix(int) RETURNS matrix LANGUAGE SQL AS
$$ select * from matrix where id = $1 $$;

CREATE FUNCTION multiply(matrix, matrix) RETURNS matrix LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$$
DECLARE matrix1 = $1.matrix_data;
        matrix2 = $2.matrix_data;
begin
   ...
end;
$$;
```

Then you can call the matrix multiplication as:

```
SELECT * FROM multiply(matrix(1), matrix(2));
```

You could even insert into the table the product of two other matrices:

```
INSERT INTO matrix (matrix_data)
SELECT matrix_data FROM multiply(matrix(1), matrix(2));
```

Comment: Good ... until the matrix changes size. +1

Comment: @CADbloke, I assume you mean that we update a matrix to one of a different size.  The thing is however that this doesn't pose any particular problems.  You have to handle the size invariances in your multiplication functions either way.  We work on values (and values do not change) rather than objects or mutable types in this case....

Comment: yup, that's what I meant. My use-case would occasionally add extra items in both dimensions, it's basically and X,Y distance table. Agreed, it's not an impossible task, just fiddly.